# Tag a version automatically - coralogix

Tags: logging, tags

I am trying to tag a version in Coralogix. I know it can be achieved manually with the Coralogix UI.
I have an xml file which contains the configuration of Coralogix. I want to know if there is a way to tag the specific version of the application.

my coralogix-configuration.xml file:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="coralogix" class="com.coralogix.sdk.appenders.CoralogixLogbackAppender">
               <companyId>{{.Values.coralogix_company_id}}</companyId>
               <privateKey>{{.Values.coralogix_key}}</privateKey>
               <applicationName>service</applicationName>
               **<tags>{{.Values.service_version}}</tags>** *Here the version will be specified*
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file>./logs/service_log.log</file>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
          <fileNamePattern>./logs/service_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
          <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
          <totalSizeCap>100MB</totalSizeCap>
          <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
      </rollingPolicy>
      <encoder>
          <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
    </appender>


    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="coralogix"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I have read the documentation and tried to talk with their support but none seem to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the scenario which you should implement:

1. Add the version to the log:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %version [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
```

2. In Coralogix -> Data flow -> Parsing rules add a rule to parse your log from text to json object so you will get a field %version as a key
   Your logs should look like after parsing:

```
{
  "timestamp":"11:45:50.123",
  "version":"1.23",
  "thread":"thread1",
  "level":"info",
  "logger":"my_logger",
  "msg":"This is an event"
}
```

3. This way you can create a custom webhook where you will use the field version.

Custom webhook documentation: https://coralogix.com/docs/alert-webhooks/ 
Method: Post
URL: https://webapi.[domain]/api/v1/external/tags/
Headers:

```
{
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "Bearer <Data flow -> API keys -> Alerts, Rules, Tags key>"
}
```

Body:

```
{
  "name": "$version",
  "timestamp": "$EVENT_TIMESTAMP",
  "application": [
    "test-app"
  ],
  "subsystem": [
    "test-subsystem"
  ]
}
```

4. Once there is a webhook we can create an alert: New Value type with the search query:

```
_exists_: "version"
```

Key to track: "version"

Recipients: the webhook you created in the step 3

Doc: https://coralogix.com/docs/new-value-alerts/

Summary:
The alert will be triggered when there will be new value in the field version. The alert will send a webhook to Coralogix Tags API endpoint and the tag will be created.